# Python Requests Post Failing With 500 Error

Tags: c#, python, python-requests

I am using this excellent project on GitHub (https://github.com/cjyoung/MouseBitesWPF).  However, that is written in C# and I really need something written in Python.  I have boiled that code down to the absolute bare bones of what it needs to work and came up with this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DisneyFinderSmaller
{
    class Program
    {

        static CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        static internal string rootUrl = "https://disneyworld.disney.go.com";
        static internal string siteUrl = "/dining/";        
        static internal string diningSearchUrl = "/finder/dining-availability";


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LaunchSearchInstance();
            string test = Console.ReadLine();

        }


        private static void LaunchSearchInstance()
        {
            string result = getCookiesFromRequest(rootUrl + siteUrl, "", "GET");
            string pep_csrf = "";
            Match match = Regex.Match(result, "<input[^>]*name=['\"]pep_csrf['\"][^>]*value=['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]*[^>]>", RegexOptions.Singleline & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            pep_csrf = match.Groups[1].ToString();
            ConductSearch(pep_csrf);
        }

        private static void ConductSearch(string pep_csrf)
        {


            string postString = string.Format("&searchDate={1}" +
                                                "&skipPricing=true" +
                                                "&searchTime={2}" +
                                                "&partySize={3}" +
                                                "&id={0}%3BentityType%3Drestaurant" +
                                                "&type=dining" +
                                                "&pep_csrf={4}",
                                                   "293704",
                                                    "2015-11-18",
                                                    "80000714",
                                                    "2",
                                                    pep_csrf);

            string result = getCookiesFromRequest(rootUrl + diningSearchUrl, postString, "POST");
            System.Console.WriteLine(result);

        }

        private static String getCookiesFromRequest(string url, string postString, string method = "POST")
        {
            String result = "";
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postString);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = method;
            request.Referer = rootUrl + siteUrl;
            request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
            if (method == "POST")
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                postStream.Close();
            }
            try
            {

                HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                result = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                responseStream.Close();
                webResponse.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IOException source: {0}", ex.Source);
            }
            return result;
        }
     }
}
```

In my efforts to translate this to Python using Requests, I have come up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests


url = "https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/dining/"
url2 = "https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/dining/finder/dining-availability"


session = requests.Session()

tokenRequest = session.get(url, headers=header)
start = tokenRequest.content.find('''id="pep_csrf"''')
pep = tokenRequest.content[start+21:tokenRequest.content.find('>',start+22)-1]

raw = "&searchDate=2015-11-18&skipPricing=true&searchTime=80000714&partySize=2&id=293704%3BentityType%3Drestaurant&type=dining&pep_csrf=" +  pep

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'referer': 'https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/dining/',
    'method' : 'POST'   
}
result = session.post(url2, data=raw, headers=headers)

print result.status_code
```

But this doesn't work and returns a status code of 500.

Any thoughts on where things are going wrong?  I have been hanging my head against the wall for a few days and any insight at all would be so appreciated.

Comment: Can you capture both requests with wireshark and post the http requests (including headers) and responses here?

Comment: I would add a `logging` object in different points in your code so you can see where it is failing. You can also enclose your code in a try/except statement and use the `traceback` module to print/log the stack trace, though you couldn't want that in your production code.

Comment: matcheek - I would love to do that, but I don't have much (or any) experience with Wireshark.  I downloaded it and ran it and I have no idea what you would be looking for.  Any thing I should be on the lookout for so I can post here?

Comment: @otictac1 you could set up a filter for particular port, 80, or whichever you use and particular IP address. Once you do that it should be straight forward to figure out which requests come from you.
Then, right click on the particular packet in the main Wireshark window, "Follow TCP stream" and you should see full http request and response.

Comment: @matcheek Okay, I  am getting closer, but when I do that it is complete jibberish like this `..Disney Enterprises, Inc1"0 ..U....disneyworld.disney.go.com0.."0
..*.H..
..........0..
......R....Vy.9Z...j.....}......d..........N..K..`

Comment: I decided to just make this work in C# so I am good for now. Working great in C#